# What is a chemical element?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I would like to know what is the difference between a chemical element and a type of atom? Can  anyone give the definition, please!

Answer (score 3):

From a scientific standpoint, there is no difference.  Elements=Atoms=the 100 or so basic building blocks of chemistry.

This is purely conjecture, but I suspect that the term/concept "elements" pre-date "atoms" (at least atoms as we know them today).  I could see "elements" referring to the macroscopic description, e.g. a jar of carbon (graphite), but it may not have been realized back-in-the-day that these were aggregations of many carbon atoms.

"Atom" strikes me as quantum scale, and "Element" strikes me as something on the macroscopic scale, perhaps hearkening back to the pre-atomic days.  But really, there is no difference.

Comment: I agree that the distinction is mostly academic/linguistic. I suppose the one issue to clarify is the matter of isotopes; not every neutral atom of a given element is identical, and grouping by element only takes into account protons, so that probably bears mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

At the chemical level, an "element" is "a type of atom"; the later is literally the simple definition of the former (with "type" being further clarified as a specific number of protons found in the nuclei of all atoms of that element). So for most purposes, the two are one and the same.

There is sometimes a distinction made in chemistry literature between a substance in its "molecular" form as opposed to its "elemental" or "atomic" form. "Molecular nitrogen" refers to the pure form of natural gaseous nitrogen, N<sub>2</sub>. "Elemental nitrogen" or "Atomic nitrogen" refers not only to the pure substance, but in its unbonded, monoatomic form. Most non-noble gases don't naturally exist this way, and in fact a few, like nitrogen, are far more stable in diatomic gas form than any other. However, when making stoichiometric calculations, it's an important distinction; a mole of "molecular" nitrogen is double the mass of a mole of "atomic" nitrogen, because each nitrogen molecule is two nitrogen atoms.

Further confusing things is that depending on who you talk to, the "elemental" form of a substance could be its "natural pure" form, the form the pure substance exists in at room temperature and pressure, or its "atomic" form as single unbonded atoms. If there is a difference, as there is with gases, then the term "elemental" can be very confusing.

And perhaps most confusing of all is that the definition of "pure" a lab chemist might use is different from the definition that a nuclear physicist would use, because of the existence of isotopes. While atoms of a specific element must have a constant number of protons in order to be that element, many elements can exist for a measurable length of time with varying numbers of neutrons. Some have multiple "stable" isotopes (which will exist indefinitely in their current state without decay); chlorine, for example, is stable with either 35 or 37 total nucleons. Usually (but not always), the chemistry of various isotopes is unaffected; where it matters, in the molar mass of reagents, an average of the "naturally-occurring stable isotopes", weighted by percentage in naturally occurring form, is used and is close enough for chemists' purposes.

However, what a chemist would call "pure chlorine" would be unusable for a nuclear physicist researching molten salt reactors, because of the differing behaviors of Chlorine-35 and Chlorine-37 when bombarded with neutrons. Chlorine-35 can capture a neutron to become Chlorine-36, which then degrades (with a rather long half-life of 300,000 years give or take a few thousand) into Argon-36 and Sulfur-36, neither of which are chlorine and therefore don't produce the halide salt that is necessary for the chemistry of the reactor design, and sulfur being highly corrosive to the alloys used for the reactor vessel and coolant loops.

Comment: 1) I do not see how your answer is substantially different than mine, except for 2) your involvement of isotopes--which are never the issue when talking about "atoms" in the context of "elements"--these are solely based on proton count.